# Mysql : get previous date and breaking loop

Tags: mysql, date, loops

i'm trying to get the next and previous row from a mysql table.
The problem is not in acquiring previous BUT to **break a loop** in the prev query (or next, it's the same).

Here the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and datas :

```
INSERT INTO `my_events` (`id`, `title`, `date_start`) VALUES
    (1, 'event prev 1', '2014-04-06 10:00:00'),
    (2, 'current event', '2014-04-08 11:00:00'),
    (3, 'event prev 2', '2014-04-06 10:00:00'),
    (4, 'event prev far', '2014-04-04 08:00:00');
```

where you are on 'current event'  page, this is the request to get the closest previous event

```
SELECT * FROM my_events
WHERE id != 2 AND date_start <= '2014-04-08 11:00:00'
ORDER BY date_start DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

it return the event 'event prev 2'. Fine.

**Now, the bug** :

on 'event prev 2' :

```
SELECT * FROM my_events
WHERE id != 3 AND date_start <= '2014-04-06 10:00:00'
ORDER BY date_start DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

return 'event prev 1' : **OK**

on 'event prev 1' :

```
SELECT * FROM my_events
WHERE id != 1 AND date_start <= '2014-04-06 10:00:00'
ORDER BY date_start DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

return 'event prev 2' : **LOOP**

the event 4 (event prev far) never appear

Have any ideas on how to resolv this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but your **event prev 1** and **event prev 2** have the exact same date & time and your using `<=` when comparing the dates, so when you are on any of them, you will always get the other one. If you change the `<=` to `<`, you will get **event prev far**.

Comment: @erwane - Adding to this solution, I would change the WHERE to `WHERE id != 1 AND (date_start < '2014-04-06 10:00:00' OR (id < 1 AND date_start = '2014-04-06 10:00:00'))` This code should allow you to select the same time based events as long as the ID is smaller. Then based on your loop, you can get the same times for each smaller id but never repeat

Comment: @Racil : there can be lots of events at the same time, it's a national calendar for events.

Comment: @AgRizzo : yes, but there can be 3 or more events at the exact same time, and ID is not sure. And to add complexity, the events are not publish in right order. An event with id 10 can be after an id 40. It was published before, but start after.

I think the only way is to get all ID for the exact same time, note them in session (php), and base the next and prev on this immutable ordred array of ids and at the first (or last) item, get the previous item in time with < (not <=)